# Как отредактировать орфографический словарь в Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Когда вы пишете что-то с опечаткой, Chrome подчеркивает слово красным, если после этого щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши - он предложит замену или добавить слово в словарь.

Эти пункты рядом - бывает, что добавляю слово в словарь вместо того, чтобы заменить его. Как отредактировать этот словарь и убрать из него добавленные вручную слова?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1)

> Google Chrome -> Настройки -> Языки -> Пользовательский словарь для проверки правописания

Вариант 2) Открываем папку, в которой лежит Google Chrome. У меня это

> C:\Users\Артем\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

У вас, скорее всего, что-то похожее. Уточнить можно, кликнув правой кнопкой по ярлыку Google Chrome и посмотрев в его свойствах Рабочую папку.

В этой папке должна лежать ещё одна папка Dictionaries, а в ней — файл ru-RU-2-0.bdic Его следует удалить (можете и просто куда-то перенести, если боитесь, что что-то сломается). После этого, когда вы снова откроете Chrome (файл можно удалить, только закрыв браузер), программа автоматически скачает словарь.

Думаю такой способ поможет

Comment: а как его подправить, не удаляя - часть слов я добавил туда осознанно)

Comment: Google Chrome -> Настройки -> Языки -> Пользовательский словарь для проверки правописания

Comment: "Пользовательский словарь для проверки правописания" - этого у меня нет

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста тогда версию Google Chrome. У меня на данный момент 49.0.2623.110

Comment: Версия 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit) Mac